# No funciona un Switch [php]

Tags: php, html, mysql

INTRA-Nielsen | Agendamiento

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/styles.css">
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<!-- Theme style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
<!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
     folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
<!-- iCheck -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css">
<!-- Morris chart -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/morris/morris.css">
<!-- jvectormap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
<!-- Date Picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
<!-- Daterange picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css">
<!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendario/dhtmlgoodies_calendar/dhtmlgoodies_calendar.css?random=20051112">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendario/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendario/dhtmlgoodies_calendar/dhtmlgoodies_calendar.js?random=20060118"></script>

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- DIV FLOTANTE FRENTE DE PAGINA -->
    <section>
        <div id="capa_modal" class="div_modal" onclick="javascript:cerrar_div_modal()"></div>
        <div id="capa_para_edicion" class="div_contenido"></div>
    </section>

    <!-- Encabezado pagina -->
    <?php
        session_start();
        if (!empty($_SESSION['iduser']))
        {
            include('../../home_header.php');
        }else{
           header("location:/index.php");
        }
        session_write_close();
    ?>

    <!-- Menu Principal -->      
    <aside class="main-sidebar">
        <section class="sidebar">
        <?php
            include('../../home_menu.php');
        ?>
        </section>
    </aside>

    <!-- Contenido Central de Pagina -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content-sidebar">
            <?php 
                $iduser=$_SESSION['iduser'];
                $op=$_GET['turno'];

                switch ($op) {
                    case 'listado1':        include('dash_turnos.php'); break;
                    case 'listado2':        include('dash_carga-turnos.php'); break;
                    case 'listado3':        include('dash_turno-propio.php'); break;
                    case 'listado4':        include('dash_turno-dia.php');break;
                    case 'listado5':        include('dash_asigna-ejecutivo.php');break;
                    default:                include('home.php');break;


                             }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->



    <!-- Pie de Pagina -->
    <?php 
        include('../../home_footer.php');
    ?>  

    <!-- Barra Lateral Derecha -->
    <?php 
        include('../../home_control_sidebar.php');
    ?>


    <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
    immediately after the control sidebar -->
    <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>

</div><!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script src="/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->

 <script>
  $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<!--<script src="/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
<script src="/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
<script src="/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->

<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="/dist/js/demo.js"></script>

<script src="/js/sidebar.js"></script>
<script src="../agendamiento_ordenes/ajax.js"></script>
```

**Los cases** funcionan hasta el 4, probé ingresando **break** después de hacer el *include* de cada case pero no funcionó.

Y acá están las clases, para mostrar que los nombres son idénticos y no es un problema de nombres.

Al momento de cargar la pagina correspondiente a listado 5, no muestra nada por pantalla ni siquiera muestra un echo ni nada por el estilo, deduzco que no esta llegando al case ya que en la url me indica ..

> /home_dash_turnos.php?turno=5
>   [image: BD]

Comment: Hola buenos días por favor coloca el código para poderte ayudar mejor. No es una buena practica colocar imágenes

Comment: @YoelRodriguez ahí baje las imágenes y introduje solo código, disculpa soy nuevo en el foro.

Comment: @felipeandrade, ¿y los `break` al final de cada `case` y cuál es el valor de `$op`?

Comment: Puede ser que te esté dando fallo el propio include de esa opción. Prueba a poner un **die("hola");** delante del include y mira si aparece en pantalla. Si es así el problema es del archivo dash_asigna_ejecutivo.php

Comment: @felipe porque en lugar de de colocar listado+numero no pasas un # entero y al final de cada linea del case tienes que colocar un break que no lo estas colocando.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez no es obligatorio el break; en las opciones de un switch. No sabemos si quiere incluir todo si la opción es la primera. (Aunque es muy seguro que eso optimice su ejecución)

Comment: El Manual de PHP indica que al final de cada `case` debes colocar la instrucción `break`, a no ser que quieras evaluar por grupos de opciones. Es probable que el case 5 no esté funcionando porque el archivo que intentas incluir tiene algún error. Sería muy fácil de probar. Primero, agregar todos los breaks de rigor, y en el case que no funciona, comenta el include y coloca algo como `echo "5";` Algo así: `case 'listado5':        echo "5"; break;  //include('dash_asigna-ejecutivo.php');`

Comment: Efectivamente. DEBES. Pero no es obligatorio. El break salta la ejecución al final del switch. Por lo que si quieres pasar por los otros casos, puedes no ponerlo. :)

Comment: no los puse como entero, los volvi a cambiar como listado. Ya que no me mostraba ninguno haciendo el cambio del mismo en la bd, @jakala hice lo del die("hola"); y no muestra nada por pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Puesto que al parecer lo que afirmaste era un error, depura en estos dos niveles.

**1º Verifica el valor de `$op`**:

```
$op=$_GET['turno'];
echo $op;
```

En caso de que sea `5`, **verifica que no sea un cinco con espacios en blanco o algo por el estilo: `5(espacio)`  o `(espacio)5`...**

**2º Verifica que no sea un problema del archivo que estás incluyendo:**

```
case 5: echo "5"; break; //include('dash_asigna-ejecutivo.php');break;
```

**3º Agrega `default` al final, para ver si es que la opción 5 no se cumple:`**

Al final del switch:

```
default: echo "Por defecto. Op tiene el valor: ".$op;
```

---

@deprecated

Según dices:

> Al momento de cargar la pagina correspondiente a listado 5, no muestra
>   nada por pantalla ni siquiera muestra un echo ni nada por el estilo,
>   deduzco que no esta llegando al case ya que en la url me indica
>   ../home_dash_turnos.php?turno=listado5

En ese caso, el valor de `$op=$_GET['turno'];` será **listado5**, pero tú evalúas así:

```
  switch ($op) {
                case 1:        include('dash_turnos.php'); break;
                case 2:        include('dash_carga-turnos.php'); break;
                case 3:        include('dash_turno-propio.php'); break;
                case 4:        include('dash_turno-dia.php');break;
                case 5:        include('dash_asigna-ejecutivo.php');break;
               }
```

En ese contexto, no hay un case 5, sino un case `listado5`.

O bien, igualas el código para que responda así:

```
../home_dash_turnos.php?turno=5
```

O bien agregas esa posibilidad a los case:

```
case "listado5":  include('dash_asigna-ejecutivo.php');break;
```

Comment: fue un error de edición, el valor de $op=$_GET['turno']; es 5

Comment: @felipeandrade aplica los tres niveles de depuración indicados en el EDIT de la respuesta.

Comment: hice la depuración en 3 niveles y bueno, el echo de $op muestra su valor dependiendo del case, en el caso de case listado 1 el valor lo muestra como listado1, hice el echo comentando la url y tampoco muestra el echo... al parecer no muestra nada que se ingrese en el case 5

Comment: Si pones un bloque `switch` completo, con la opción `default` al final, te mostrará lo que hay en `$op` en el case 5. Si no muestra nada, sería interesante que edites la pregunta, poniendo la parte del código que envía la información que recuperas posteriormente en la variable `$op`. Si el case 1 dice `listado1` es muy probable que en uno o varios casos la palabra `listado` venga agregada al número.

Comment: depure con el echo"5" y tampoco nada, al momento de dar click en la opcion la url me muestra que va a listado5 pero no muestra anda por pantalla

Comment: @felipeandrade coloca el código completo para revisarlo.

Comment: e hecho una edición con el código completo, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No veo en el código de dónde sacas la url que es enviada al servidor: `/home_dash_turnos.php?turno=...` hay que ver cómo se está formando esa url... ¿o se obtiene de una base de datos? Sería importante ver la parte del código que hace esa manipulación. En todo lo que has puesto no veo esa parte, @felipeandrade

Comment: se obtiene de una base de datos

Comment: Entiendo @felipeandrade . Si colocas la parte del código que obtiene los datos de la base de datos y los envía al servidor, sería útil para determinar donde se encuentra el problema. No todo el código, sino solamente esa parte que hace la consulta, obtiene los datos y los envía al servidor.

Comment: el problema no es en la base, solo se estan sacando opciones de ella que estan ya predestinadas las url como se muestran en las imagenes que adjunte.

Comment: Pero... @felipeandrade es posible que haya un error en la parte que envía la información, o sea, que hace el POST. Quizá ahí hagas alguna manipulación que distorsione los valores recibidos de la base de datos, por eso sería bueno ver esa parte para evaluar el problema. De acuerdo a todo lo dicho hasta ahora, creo que el problema está ahí.